# Huge finite sets

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, median

> Consider the set
>   $$S=\{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots,123456789\},$$
>   which consists of all positive integers whose digits strictly increase from left to right. This set is finite. What is the median of the set?

Like ... how do I start?  I thought it would be 512 (which is clearly wrong).

Comment: Why did you think it is 512?

Comment: It might be easier to consider a simple example first - what's the median of $\{1, 2, 3\}$? How about $\{1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9\}$?

Comment: Do it in increasing bases.  Start in base 2, then base 3 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Assuming that the numbers in the set are ascendantly ordered the counts of $x$-digit numbers can be symbolically presented as

$$
\binom{9}{1},\binom{9}{2},\binom{9}{3},\binom{9}{4},\binom{9}{5},\binom{9}{6},\binom{9}{7},\binom{9}{8},\binom{9}{9}.
$$

We see that the median of the set is the first 5-digit number. What is it?

> 12345

Comment:

If $\binom{9}{0}$ were present (and the cardinality of the set were the even number $2^9=512$), the virtual "median" would be exactly between  $\binom{9}{4}$ and $\binom{9}{5}$. But the numbers consisting of 0 digits do not exist. Therefore the median shifts one position to the right from its virtual value.

Comment: Doesn't this representation show that the median is the same as the median of the $5$-digit numbers? Also, it might not be clear to everyone how these numbers can be presented as these binomial coefficients. A bit more exposition would be nice.

Comment: @Servaes That's what I thought too. But no. You need to start with the virtual $\binom{9}{0}$ to get the symmetry. Then you have $10$ binomial coefficients.  I think the answer should be edited to make that clear.

Comment: @EthanBolker You're absolutely right! And I agree that the answer should be improved.

Comment: @Servaes The binomial coefficients $\binom{9}{x}$ represent counts of $x$-digit numbers. The median would be exactly between  $\binom{9}{4}$ and $\binom{9}{5}$ if $\binom{9}{0}$ were present. But it is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Let's count the cardinality of $S$. For each digit $1$ to $9,$ if it is part of a given number, its position is fixed. That is, if I know that a certain number in $S$ contains the digits $1,2,3,5,7,$ and no others, then the only element of $S$ satisfying this is $12357.$ Then $|S|=2^{9}-1=511,$ since I have $2$ options for every digit (in the number or not), and $9$ digits, but I cannot have a number with no digits.

The median is then the number in the $2^{8}=256$ position in this list. I observe that there is only $1$ $9$-digit number, there are $9$ $8$-digit numbers, there are $\binom{9}{2}=36$ $7$-digit numbers, and similarly there are $\binom{9}{k}$ $(9-k)$-digit numbers, for $k=0$ to $8$ (just choose which digits to leave out).

Observe that the count of all numbers in $S$ with $5$ or more digits is then equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{4}\binom{9}{k}=256,$ and $255=\sum_{k=5}^{8}\binom{9}{k},$ the count of all numbers in $S$ with $4$ or fewer digits. Therefore the median is the smallest $5$-digit number, or $12345$.